# Can someone please explain generics in detain in this piece of code?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am not able to understand what 'out T' is doing in this piece of kotlin code. Can someone explain this in detail?

```
sealed class ResultWrapper<out T> {
  data class Success<out T>(val value: T): ResultWrapper<T>()
  data class GenericError(val code: Int? = null, val error: ErrorResponse? = null): ResultWrapper<Nothing>()
  object NetworkError: ResultWrapper<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T just means the class is is using objects of a particular type, but we don't know what that is at compile time, so we are just going to call it T for the moment (you could use any letter, T is just a convention).

This makes the code generic. What we wouldn't want to do is to use Any instead of T, because later on we might want to call specific methods on objects of type T without have to do casting.